# How can I make my ILI9486 Display not show my frame until I'm done? (Flickering!)

Tags: cortex-m, lpc, tft

I have a ILI9486 TFT display and I am using an LPC1768 with it.

The issue I am having is in the following:

```
        if(!(LPC_GPIO1->FIOPIN & (1 << 27))) {
        TFT_Clear(Black);
        TFT_DrawButton(80,80, "First Message", White, Purple);
        TFT_Show();
    } else if ((LPC_GPIO1->FIOPIN & (1 << 28))) {
        TFT_Clear(Black);
        TFT_DrawButton(80,80, "Second Message", White, Blue);
        TFT_Show();
    }
```

What happens is that the screen flashes and flickers black and then show the other box. If I don't use `TFT_Clear(Black);` it writes this over the old box and there's little bits of it left. what I want is for the screen to not show what I'm writing to it's memory until I decide it's time basically, Or at least for it to not show the `TFT_Clear()` function until I am done writing the rest.

This is my TFT_Clear() function for reference:

```
void TFT_Clear (int16_t color) 
{
    unsigned int   i;

    LCD_WindowMax();

    TFT_StartWrite();
    for(i = 0; i < (WIDTH*HEIGHT); i++) {
        TFT_SendData(color);
    }
    TFT_Show();
}
```

`TFT_StartWrite()` sets the pins (CS RD etc) according to the datasheet and the `TFT_Show()` turns the CS back on after the Writing is on.

[This is the Display's datasheet for reference.](https://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/controller/ILI9486L.pdf)

I also had this issue when showing a circle move up and down. It'd just get dim and have a very strange flickering, Even when I didn't use the clear function and just redrew a black circle in the previous position before drawing the new one

Comment: What grahpics library are you using? Does it support frame buffers?

Comment: @Jeroen3 I am actually using my own. Writing it as I go https://github.com/kamhagh/ILI9486-Library

I tried using Buffers (uint16_6[320][480]) but although it compiled it wouldn't execute properly no matter what I did. my debugger told me it's stuck at "SystemInit();" which is CMSIS's clock initialization

Comment: I just tried the same code but I just write to a random buffer that size. it doesn't execute properly either. is it just that it's out of ram?

Comment: Probably, since you only have 64kB, and for jitter free updates you need 308kB, or an LCD with external frame buffer.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I don't know if mine has it but I take it as that my LCD is my limitation? or my MCU? maybe I should look into the stm32f4 MCUs with integrated lcd drivers or some other LCD?

Comment: There is only one copy of frame memory in the ILI9486L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most graphics libraries use a frame buffer, and copy this to the LCD in one go. Preferably with DMA.

This frame buffer keeps one full frame in memory. The advantage is quick rendering, and glitch free updates. The drawback is a large memory footprint.

The ILI9486L only has one *frame memory*, and you can only directly read/write on this memory. The LCD is continously refreshed from this same memory.
The controller does offer features to reduce tearing effects, but it does this by advertising on which row the controller is currently refreshing.

If you update to an LPC1788 you have the option to use an external memory to keep a frame buffer.

---

A workaround could be to use a smaller section of the screen as buffer, draw in this buffer, and then update this buffer quickly with the DMA.
You might also be able to limit the effects by increasing the speed of the communication.
And of course, you can use smarter drawing algorithms so that clearing the full screen is not required. You can also read from the LCD.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think what's easier for me "A Hobbyist" is to save up for another LCD/controller and or a LPC1788 development broad. Maybe one of those STMF4 discoveries! But Sadly I'd really have to save.